# Using Perl Regex Multiline to reformat file

Tags: regex, perl, unix, command-line, multiline

I have the file with the following format:

> (Type 1 data:1)
>  B
>  B
>  (Type 1 data:2)
>  B
>  B
>  B
>   (Type 1 data:3)
>  B
>  ..

Now I want to reformat this file so that it looks like:

> (Type 1 data:1) B B
>  (Type 1 data:2) B B B
>  (Type 1 data:3) B
>   
>  ...

My approach was to use perl regex in command line,

```
cat file | perl -pe 's/\n(B)/ $1/smg'
```

My reasoning was to replace the new line character with space.
but it doesn't seem to work. can you please help me? Thanks

Comment: Please drop the useless 'cat'. perl -pe '...' reads STDIN or a file or files without that overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The -p reads a line at a time, so there is nothing after the "\n" to match with.

```
perl -pe 'chomp; $_ = ($_ =~ /Type/) ? "\n".$_ : " ".$_'
```

this does almost what you want but puts one extra newline at the beginning and loses the final newline.

Answer (score 4):

If the only place that `(` shows up is at the beginning of where you want your lines to start, then you could use this command.

```
perl -l -0x28 -ne's/\n/ /g;print"($_"if$_' < file
```

- [`-l`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2a-l%2a%5b_octnum_%5d) causes [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) to add `\n` on the end of each line it prints.
- [`-0x28`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2a-0%2a%5b_octal%2fhexadecimal_%5d) causes it to split on `(` instead of on `\n`.
- [`-n`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2a-n%2a) causes it to loop on the input. Basically it adds `while(<>){chomp $_;` to the beginning, and `}` at the end of what ever is in `-e`.
- `s/\n/ /g`
- `print "($_" if $_` The `if $_` part just stops it from printing an extra line at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little more involved as `-n` and `-p` fit best for processing one line at a time while your requirement is to combine several lines, which means you'd have to maintain state for a while.

So just read the entire file in memory and apply the regex like this:

```
perl -lwe ^
"local $/; local $_ = <>; print join q( ), split /\n/ for m/^\(Type [^(]*/gsm"
```

Feed your file to this prog on STDIN using input redirection (`<`).

Note this syntax is for the Windows command line. For Bash, use single quotes to quote the script.